# PHP Search values in array - Return true if all are numbers, false if not

Tags: php, arrays, search

Ok, Stupid question here...  just trying to do a search in an array to be sure all of the values are numeric, if not, I need to return false.  What's the quickest way to do this.  This array could be HUGE.  By the way, it's not a multi-dimensional array, and doesn't have any sub-arrays within it.  It's just a one level array... example:

```
array(1, 5, 6, 2, 44, 92, 50, string);
```

This should return false, cause string is one of the values in the array and is not a number.  I mean, is there a faster way to do this than using `foreach` on the array and using `intval` on every value??

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function -

```
$count = count($your_array);

for($index=0; $index<$count; $index++)
{
    if( !is_numeric($your_array[index]) )
        return false;
}
```

Comment: is_numeric is checking the array

Comment: @tttony: Sorry, forgot to index it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks, guess I'm going with this one since it has the most up votes.  No offense guys.

Answer (score 3):

```
  if(in_array(false, array_map("is_numeric", array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "string"))))
    return false;
```

I have not researched the performance, sorry. But these are inbuilt functions which are allegedly faster than anything custom one can write...

Comment: haven't seen that function before. Nice Info this should be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $value)
{
    if(!is_numeric($value))
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: and why have you put the braces on line 3?

Comment: it was a shorthand if statement which is `(condition ? true : false)` but it doesn't work in that situation. Been a while since I used one.